# springdoc-openui swagger url default to petstore api and not disabling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I am using **springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui** dependency and **spring boot version is 3.0.2** with **JDK 17** but when I am hitting **http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html** its showing default petstore API not my application API..

Below are the dependencies which I am using :

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
           <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.2</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <artifactId>org.webjars</artifactId>
                   <groupId>swagger-ui</groupId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/swagger-ui -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
           <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
           <version>4.8.1</version>
       </dependency>
```

and in application.yaml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: '/swagger-ui.html'
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

but it seems **disable-swagger-default-url** is not working in this case. Please let me know how can I get rid of this default petstore api and able to hit my application api.

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for this Pracheer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746912/springdoc-doesnt-work-webmvcconfigurationsupport
The answer of Stalowy brought me to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration in yaml file is correct, maybe you should upgrade the version of `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` to 2.1.0, and you can remove the related configuration about `swagger-ui` dependency from the pom. Hope this helps.