# Springdoc doesn't work WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am working on old legacy project where spring boot was configured using WebMvcConfigurationSupport and now need to set up swagger ui using spring doc. Unfortunately it's not working properly when @EnableWebMvc is disabled.

When I have this

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.17.1/").resourceChain(false);
```

Default ui with petstore is loaded.

With @EnableWebMvc it works but core app functionality is broken as all validators and front-end don't work. So I can't use it.

Via Debug I see that SwaggerIndexPageTransformer is not called.

What should I do?

Comment: not sure if is the same problem..but I'm trying to configure spring boot 3 with the new swagger "springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui". In my project I have to extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport but it seems that extending this brake the swagger ui.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found one solution when i have tried debugging the springdoc code. I noticed that there is class `SwaggerWebMvcConfigurer` which has method `addResourceHandler()`. Because we have used `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` this method is not triggered in my opinion (For example `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` delegating somehow addResourceHandlers upper in class hierarchy, I am not sure).

So, this is my code which helped:

```
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@Import({
        org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
        org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
        org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
        org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
        org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class
})
    public class SwaggerConfig { 
    
        private final SwaggerIndexTransformer swaggerIndexTransformer;
        
            public CloudServletConfig(SwaggerIndexTransformer swaggerIndexTransformer) {
                this.swaggerIndexTransformer = swaggerIndexTransformer;
            }
        
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui*/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
                    .resourceChain(false)
                    .addTransformer(swaggerIndexTransformer);
        }
```

I'm, just doing the same what `SwaggerWebMvcConfigurer` does. I think so :D

Comment: I will provide more detailed information later, because I've found a way to make it works. Some minor code corrections

Comment: Thanks, this `.resourceChain(false).addTransformer(swaggerIndexTransformer)` was the missing point in my case.